# GnuPG - How can Ubuntu encrypt messages automatically

Tags: gnupg

I am running a 12.04LTS Ubuntu Server (Linux myserver 3.2.0-52-generic-pae #78-Ubuntu SMP Fri Jul 26 16:43:19 UTC 2013 i686 athlon i386 GNU/Linux) with a FQDN and an Exim4 Mailserver.
User Alice has UID1000 and is getting the messages from root, messages send to root by local services and is getting messages from various cron jobs executed by root and Alice.
I have also generated a GnuPG keypair for alice@myFQDN.net.

What i want to do, is that the system encrypts the messages generated locally "automatically" sent to root, generated by root and generated by Alice.

So i do not know, if i have to tell the system, the services or Exim to encrypt the messages.

Kindly waiting for your help and a hint in the wright direction,
elrippo.

Comment: What are you trying to achieve in the first place? I guess from the post you want an attacker to be unable to read the messages arriving in Alice's mailbox? So you want all the messages encrypted with Alice being the sole GPG recipient - despite the recipient of the mail header? I warn you that this does not protect against message integrity or message source, nor the contents of the mailbox as the key is public and an attacker can add/remove mail messages anyway.

Comment: What are you using as a delivery agent on the system? In case you're using Procmail, you can pipe the message through a simple script encrypting it, although that does not account for the OpenPGP MIME header, but I'm sure there's a tool for that.

Comment: Hy gertvdijk.

Thank you for your answer.

I am simply trying to achieve to encrypt all messages generated by the system, not every meassge that i get. If i fetch my messages via IMAP, i want them to be encrypted. I am aware, that i can not keep my messages "safe" in case of a brake in, but i don't want them to be sent via TLS as "plain text" over the internet.

No, i am using Exim4, with famd and courier.

Kind regards.